# Can I install the Custom Document Well (vertical tabs) extension for Visual Studio 2019?

Tags: tabs, extension, visual-studio-2019

The [Custom Document Well extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CustomDocumentWell) is only available for Visual Studio 2017.  Is there a way to install it for Visual Studio 2019?  Specifically, I only care about the vertical tabs feature.

As of the time of writing this question, the current version of Visual Studio 19 is 16.0.0 and the current version of the Custom Document Well extension is 15.06.

Comment: It looks like they are planning on integrating these features into VS2019 directly and abandoning the extension. You can vote for your favorite features here: [https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/465490/update-support-for-custom-document-well-to-visual.html](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/465490/update-support-for-custom-document-well-to-visual.html).

Comment: Also, the vertical-tabs-specific discussion is here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/467369/vertical-group-tab.html

Comment: A Microsoft PM [posted](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/467369/vertical-group-tab.html?childToView=650543#comment-650543) a survey about tab usage: https://www.surveymonkey.com/r/ZTM73JL

Answer (score 82, accepted):

## Update #2

**Vertical tabs are out of preview and are [now officially part of Visual Studio 2019 v16.4](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/tis-the-season-visual-studio-2019/)!**

## Update #1

The new "Vertical Document Tabs" feature is [part of Visual Studio 2019 version 16.4 Preview 2](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releases/2019/release-notes-preview?view=vs-2019#vertdoctabs).  There is also a [dedicated blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/document-management-improvements-vertical-document-tabs-are-here/).

---

## Original answer

1. Download [`CustomDocWell.vsix`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.CustomDocumentWell)
2. Unzip the file, e.g. rename it to `CustomDocWell.vsix.zip` and extract the contents
3. Download the workaround [`extension.vsixmanifest`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/akeeton/18db2d9c2bc6c97756bd70d3af252a26/raw/0bf3e2f56408ee932a3ec5be14bbbbc0c8d2eb6d/extension.vsixmanifest) ([non-raw page](https://gist.github.com/akeeton/18db2d9c2bc6c97756bd70d3af252a26#file-extension-vsixmanifest))

   - The only change is that the upper bound of the `InstallationTarget` version has been removed
4. Replace the original `extension.vsixmanifest` with the workaround file
5. Download the workaround [`manifest.json`](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/akeeton/18db2d9c2bc6c97756bd70d3af252a26/raw/bbe583aeb69c4dd2fd0e83d58594996547fcd499/manifest.json) ([non-raw page](https://gist.github.com/akeeton/18db2d9c2bc6c97756bd70d3af252a26#file-manifest-json))

   - The only change is the `sha256` for `extension.vsixmanifest` has been recalculated
6. Replace the original `manifest.json` with the workaround file
7. Zip the contents into a new `CustomDocWell.zip`

   - **Important**: Make sure the root of the zip file is at the level of `extension.vsixmanifest` and `manifest.json`, as well as the other files and folders.  The root of the zip file **should not** be a folder named `CustomDocWell`.
8. Rename to `CustomDocWell.vsix`
9. Run the VSIX file

If you don't get any errors you'll still get a warning when you open Visual Studio 2019:

[image: Deprecation warning]

The extension will still work; the [Learn more link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/synchronously-autoloaded-extensions?view=vs-2019) explains more.

The settings are under *Tools > Options > Productivity Power Tools > Custom Document Well*.

## Errors

If you get an error it's likely that the `sha256` of `extension.vsixmanifest` is incorrect.  You can try calculating it on your own (PowerShell has `Get-FileHash`) and putting it in `manifest.json`.

Comment: All this time, it was working but artificially blocked...  WOW!

Comment: Not a deal breaker but: For color coded Regex, it works for the file name only, if you try to include folder structure in the expression, it is not detected ex: .*\\Framework\\.*\.cs

Comment: Great find, I won't upgrade until 2019 had this in, but might try this. Thanks!

Comment: Read the release notes before installing visual studio updates. This workaround no longer works in Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.1.0 Preview 1.0.

Comment: In 16.1 you can re-enable synchronous loading and still use this extension. https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/updates-to-synchronous-autoload-of-extensions-in-visual-studio-2019/

Comment: @Ryan_S But how can I install it in 16.1? It's not available in extension search and manually download and install the vsix file tells me: "Already installed in all possible versions"

Comment: This work-around works fine in Visual Studio 2019 Version 16.1.3.

Comment: Rockstar. Worked great.  I wish vertical was just built in. Why are all the good feature an extension? I end up with 15 files open at times just bouncing through call chains.

Comment: You can download a ready to use Custom Document Well installer for VS 2019 with these changes from my site: https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/installing-custom-document-well-for-visual-studio-2019.html

Comment: @SergeyVlasov can you please make a new answer? I prefer your way since it's so much easier and I don't like wasting 10 minutes every time looking for your tiny comment :)

Comment: @SergeyVlasov is it possible to get it working on VS 2022? Much prefer custom document well project colouring compared to the one it comes with (seems to only colour a bit of tab rather than the whole thing)

Comment: @A.A Nico Rieck says "CDW uses a type in its UI from Visual Studio which has been removed in 2022, so you cannot get around recompiling the extension (the rest works fine). But its license makes it not possible to share the result."
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Color-coded-tabs-in-Visual-Studio/351700#T-N1582231

Comment: @SergeyVlasov strange I could not find original source code anywhere to even try to recompile it. Thanks your help

Answer (score 14):

For this workaround to work with VS 16.1, just click "Allow synchronous autoload" in the warning banner and restart VS.
It will allow the use of the deprecated sync APIs... until the feature comes build in !

For those who have hidden the banner, check this option:
Options/Environment/Extensions/Allow synchronous autoload of extensions

Answer (score 7):

In addition to [Andrew Keeto's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1421558/283499):
After step 4, in *extension.vsixmanifest* in the  section Add:

```
<InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
<InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />
```

Or update the max version:

```
<Installation InstalledByMsi="false">
    <InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Community" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Pro" />
    <InstallationTarget Version="[15.0,17.0)" Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Enterprise" />
</Installation>
<Prerequisites>
    <Prerequisite Id="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Component.CoreEditor" Version="[15.0,17.0)" DisplayName="Visual Studio core editor" />
</Prerequisites>
```

I've recalculate the SHA265 for the *manifest.json* at https://emn178.github.io/online-tools/sha256_checksum.html and replaced it with the sha265 code for extension.vsixmanifest

Comment: I didn't need to make these changes in order for it to work on the Enterprise edition.  I suspect the `Id` attribute is just a lower bound.

Comment: @hvk You only need the first installation target line. Anything higher is automatically included.

Comment: For me, it didn't work without there changes, but did work with these changes. So, if you are stuck, try this out.

Answer (score 5):

This answer is a copy of @Sergey-Vlasov 's comment. Go to his website and follow the instructions.

> You can download a ready to use Custom Document Well installer for VS 2019 with these changes from my site: https://tabsstudio.com/documentation/installing-custom-document-well-for-visual-studio-2019.html – Sergey Vlasov Jul 27 at 13:28